# Global Int autoincrement - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to take a value INT auto increment by one (I do that) on Flutter, but it have to been updating by one for the current user but the value need to be +1 respect of the last one who take this value.

To be more clear, I need an INT that auto increment by one for the current user on relationship with the other users (or document on FirebaseFirestore.)

Here I take the possibility to make it for the current user but naturally for the other this not happen.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';

import '../Modelli/immProfilo.dart';
import '../services/Database.dart';



class Prenotazione extends StatefulWidget {
  const Prenotazione({super.key});

  @override
  State<Prenotazione> createState() => _PrenotazioneState();
}

class _PrenotazioneState extends State<Prenotazione> {
  final List<bool> _tempoSelezionato = <bool>[true, false, false];
  late int _scelta;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final controlloIm = Get.put(ImagePickerController());
    final String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;
    bool vertical = false;
    Future AggiungiCampi () async {
      final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      final String? uid = user?.uid;
      FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) async {
        if (user != null) {
              QuerySnapshot querySnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('utenti').where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get();
          QueryDocumentSnapshot doc = querySnap.docs[0];
          DocumentReference docRef = doc.reference;
          await docRef.update({
            'Prenotato': true,
            'Prenotazione': FieldValue.increment(1),
            'Creazione': Timestamp.now(),
            'Tempo': _scelta,
            'uid' : user.uid,
          });
        }
      });
      //     To create new collection
      //     await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('prenotazione').doc(uid).set({
      //       'Prenotato': true,
      //      'Prenotazione': FieldValue.increment(1),
      //       'Creazione': Timestamp.now(),
      //       'Tempo': 5,
      //       'uid' : uid,
      //
      //     });
        }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Prenotazione',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              color: Colors.white,
            )),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffE5332A),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 175,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFE5332A),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profilo');
              },
              child: StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('utenti')
                      .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
                      .snapshots(),
                  // stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('utenti').snapshots(),

                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return const Text('Caricamento');
                    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
                      final String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          var doc = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                          var data = doc.data() as Map;
                          // return Text('${data['Nome']}');
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: SizedBox(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                child: controlloIm.image.value.path == 'null'
                                    ? CircleAvatar(
                                        // backgroundImage: NetworkImage('$userPhoto')),
                                        backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                            'images/utente-predefinito.jpg'))
                                    : CircleAvatar(
                                        // backgroundImage: NetworkImage('$userPhoto')),
                                        backgroundImage:
                                            NetworkImage('${data['url']}'))),
                            title: Text(
                              '${data['Nome']}',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: const SizedBox(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 20,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.circle,
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        size: 10,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 7,
                                      ),
                                      Text('Online',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                    return const Text('Qualcosa è andato storto');
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Stack(children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 420,
                width: 500,
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -110.0, 0.0),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('images/sfondo.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Prenota il tuo turno',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFFE5332A),
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Di quanto tempo avrai bisogno in bagno?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: ToggleButtons(
                            onPressed: (int newindex) {
                              setState(() {
                                 for (int i = 0; i < _tempoSelezionato.length; i++) {
                                   _tempoSelezionato[i] = i == newindex;
                                   switch(newindex){
                                     case 0:
                                       _scelta = 5;
                                       break;
                                     case 1:
                                       _scelta = 10;
                                       break;
                                     case 2:
                                       _scelta = 15;
                                       break;
                                   }
                                 }
                              });
                            },
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                          selectedBorderColor: Color(0xFF0E8639),
                          selectedColor: Colors.white,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFF0E8639),
                          color: Color(0xFF787878),
                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                              minHeight: 50.0,
                              minWidth: 120.0,
                            ),
                          isSelected: _tempoSelezionato,
                          children: [
                            Text('5 minuti'),
                            Text('10 minuti'),
                            Text('15 minuti'),
                          ],

                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(
                          '* Ricordati che una volta che avrai prenotato il bagno dovrai aspettare il tuo turno ed una volta concluso confermarlo nell’app con l’apposito pulsante di modo che possa andare la persona successiva.'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            AggiungiCampi();
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            minimumSize: Size(250, 50),
                          ),
                          child: Text('Conferma la prenotazione', style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading your code, you're loading a document specific to the current user and increments a counter in there.

If you want to increment a global counter, you'll need a global document (so one that's the same for all users). The typical way to do that is to give it a fixed/hard-coded name.

Something like:

```
DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('utenti').doc('global_counter');
await docRef.update({
  'Prenotazione': FieldValue.increment(1),
});
```

Comment: Hi man, first of all thanks for your answer, but I have other question now, If I create this doc in this mode then How can I understand which user increment it? 
Sorry maybe I not understand correctly what that means but to be clear I need to create something like “waiting room queue” and on homepage I need to display cards with name, image and a text from the user that increment this value and give them also their number (for example You are the queue number 3) and make it base on gender (name pic etc I have on a DOC connected with uid). 
Please help me 

Comment: If you want to track who last incremented the global counter, write their UID into the global counter document. I. just removed it in my answer to ensure we focus on the counter that you were asking about.

Comment: Okay man, I work on your suggestion and try to do it! 
The only one thing I need to understand is how to take the value of the last one that increase it and also display the data of the user and also the data inside the doc with counter! 
For now thanks btw 

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. If you want to display the value in your app, use a listener as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen. If there is some other transactional aspect about the update, use a transaction: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: Sorry, maybe I can explain it correctly, btw I need to take the data of the user that increment this value for the last, but also the data storage on the single user document like Name, profile image and so similar and make it together with the auto increment doc, I know how to take data from one Snapshot but I thinking if I can take a data with one snapshot from 2 doc, uid doc and also Auto increment doc… I tuinking on it 

Comment: I create the document passing to it also the user.uid but I have a problem, the value autoincrement only if the same user click  it, I try also .set instead of .upgrade but is not changing. 
I try to create a Collection called "counter" but also with add I have the same problem, it create a document but value is not autoincrementing, I don't undersand why in all fo the 2 cases.